# Java - What is the most efficient way to copy the contents of an Android Cursor into a new SQLite database of its own?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, cursor

How would you go about doing this? I have not found any good resources or solutions to this after quite a bit of googling.

Comment: Where did you get the `Cursor` from? If the answer is "from SQLite", use `ATTACH DATABASE` and migrate your data completely within SQLite, if you can. Beyond that, using a `Cursor` as a data source does not really impact Java->SQLite performance, and so all the standard rules apply (e.g., use transactions to minimize disk writes).

Comment: @CommonsWare I got the Cursor from the Contacts Provider... is that considered "from SQLite" and could I use `ATTACH DATABASE`? If not, then I will go about using the standards. Thank you!

Comment: Not really. Yes, the contacts are probably stored in a SQLite database, but it is not your database -- you have no direct filesystem access to it. I thought perhaps that you were implementing some sort of backup or archival system, or you were migrating from an unencrypted database to an encrypted one, or something like that. In those cases, you would "own" both databases, and a direct SQLite->SQLite data transfer would be an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, make sure you create a new database class, which has the tables you need. After that you can use the `insertCursorInDb` method. Also call `open()` once, this will let you write to the database.

```
public class YourDatabase extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // If you change the database schema, you must increment the database version.
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "yourdatabase.db";
    private SQLiteDatabase database;

    public YourDatabase(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    public void open() throws SQLException {
        database = this.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    private void create(SQLiteDatabase database) {
        database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE contacts (TEXT `name`, TEXT `number`)");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
        create(database);
    }

    // this function depends on the values in your cursor
    public void insertCursorInDb(Cursor cursor) {
        if (cursor != null) {
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                database.execSQL("INSERT INTO contacts(`name`, `number`) VALUES (?, ?)", new String[]{cursor.getString(0), cursor.getString(1)});
            }
            cursor.close();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

As suggested, you can also use `ContentValues`, then it will become like this:

```
// this function depends on the values in your cursor
    public void insertCursorInDb(Cursor cursor) {
        if (cursor != null) {
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put("name", cursor.getString(0));
                values.put("number", cursor.getString(1));
                database.insertOrThrow("contacts", null, values);
            }
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you.

Comment: Please mark it as answer if it helped you out :)

Comment: Of course, need to wait 4 minutes though :)

Comment: Some [helper functions](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils.html#cursorRowToContentValues%28android.database.Cursor,%20android.content.ContentValues%29) might make this easier.